# Importing customers into magento with existing passwords

Tags: magento, csv, import, passwords

I'm importing 15000 users from virtuemart into magento but have been unable to get the passwords to import correctly.

My problem is that the passwords are hashed differently.

Virtuemart HASH = md5($password.$salt);

Magento HASH = md5($salt.$password);

An example password looks like:

```
c957d358c8a79e66af10086b53b5a069:AuHg2mCXUhViqKYCLtFco22rmUCDwIFI
```

An answer has been provided below which partially solves my problem. Applying this allows my virtuemart customers to login but causes issues with the admin login and forces new users to use the virtuemart password hash format.

I now need to modify this in such a way that it checks the core hashing method, and if that fails it checks the virtuemart hashing method allowing both password formats to login.

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
public function getHash($password, $salt = false)
{
    if (is_integer($salt)) {
        $salt = $this->_helper->getRandomString($salt);
    }
    return $salt === false ? $this->hash($password) : $this->hash($password . $salt) . ':' . $salt : $this->hash($salt . $password) . ':' . $salt;
}
```

.

```
    public function validateHash($password, $hash)
{
    $hashArr = explode(':', $hash);
    switch (count($hashArr)) {
        case 1:
            // no hash
            return $this->hash($password) === $hash;
        case 2:
            // magento default hash
            return $this->hash($hashArr[1] . $password) === $hashArr[0];
        case 3:
            // virtuemart hash
            return $this->hash($password . $hashArr[1]) === $hashArr[0];        }
    Mage::throwException('Invalid hash.');
}
```

but as you can probably tell this doesnt work as i have no way to check the hash type method.

How would i go about this please ?

UPDATE - Heres my latest attempt.

```
public function validateHash($password, $hash)
{
    $hashArr = explode(':', $hash);
    if(admin_login_handling_and_api_user_accounts){
        switch (count($hashArr)) {
            case 1:
                return $this->hash($password) === $hash;
            case 2:
                return $this->hash($hashArr[1] . $password) === $hashArr[0];
        }
    } else if(Magento_customer_handling){
        switch (count($hashArr)) {
            case 1:
                return $this->hash($password) === $hash;
            case 2:
                    return $this->hash($password . $hashArr[1]) === $hashArr[0];
        }
    } else if(soap_Api_customer_handling){
        switch (count($hashArr)) {
            case 1:
                return $this->hash($password) === $hash;
            case 2:
                return $this->hash($hashArr[1] . $password) === $hashArr[0];
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed the validatehash function to include if statements but this doesnt seem to be recognised. My php skills are on the very basic side so if someone could please explain where im going wrong with this or if theres a better way to go about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends how the algorithm works in virtuemart. After a quick google it seems like it takes the password provided by the user and appends the salt (the part after the semi-colon) to the end, then md5's the value, which it compares to the password hash (the part before the semi-colon in the database).

In contrast to that Magento prepends the salt to the start of the password before md5 hashing it, rather than the end.

Long story short, the quick win should be attainable by editing `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption::validateHash` so that if `$hashArr` has a count of two it will append the hash, rather than prepend.

```
// replace
return $this->hash($hashArr[1] . $password) === $hashArr[0];
// with
return $this->hash($password . $hashArr[1]) === $hashArr[0];
```

Comment: Thankyou, it works !! After making the changes i'm able to login with the imported passwords. Brilliant. The only downside of course is that after reverting the core file back i'm unable to login again so this would have to be a permanent hack. Not that im against it, if anything it may be my only option. Ideally though i'm looking for a solution which will convert my passwords to the default magento format. I'm thinking the best approach would be to import the passwords using your method and then run an sql query in the db.

Comment: Right after researching some more i have a much better understanding of whats going on now and fully understand your code above. So joomla is hashing the passwords like so HASH = md5($password.$salt); and magento is doing the opposite HASH = md5($salt.$password); got it ! Is there anyway to convert the hash to magentos way of thinking or is it irreversible once its hashed ?

Comment: One other point id like to add is that magento should support both the salted and unsalted passwords, atleast thats what it says on the wiki page http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/customer I presumed removing the salt part after the colon would convert it to the regular unsalted md5 but this doesnt appear to be case.

Comment: You should probably research what a hash is. The only time you would be able to convert the hash would be at the point the customer is logging in, but there really isn't much point if you are are starting from scratch with only virtuemart customers. Magento does support saltless passwords, it simply stores an empty string after the colon. Your password hashes have been created with a salt though, so if you remove the salts you won't be able to validate the hash.

Comment: Hi Cags, thanks for the reply. Wouldnt keeping the joomla hash cause issues down the line ? For instance new users would be generated using the same hash format, magento updates may cause issues, etc. I've also noticed the admin cant login with the core hack in place. This is all new to me, i've never looked at encryption methods before so this is a first. Any advice you can give or material to read up on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cags, hope you dont mind but i've updated your answer with an additional replace which i found necessary to allow new customers to login. I'm still not sure how to fix the admin login problem or if any other replaces need to be applied.

Comment: The admin probably can't log in because their password was generated using the core model. The safest solution would probably be to modify that function in such a way that it checks the core method, if that fails it checks the joomla method. At that point you have the customers password so you can update the customers password to use the Magento hash method.

Comment: I think your right about the admin but after changing the password using the new model im still unable to login so something else must be going on. How would you recommend checking the method? At the moment its using return $salt === false ? I tried adding a 3rd case but that didnt appear to work.

Comment: Hey hopefully this alerts you to responses; I know it's been a few months. Cags, are you saying that you should be able to set up an IF/ELSE section of code that would check both ways of validating? This would mean that an old user or a new user could login without any problems because it would check one option, if that fails it would check the other and if either of them worked, it would give the user access to their account?

Comment: @Christian, yes, exactly. At this point you could use the customers password to convert the saved information to the 'Magento' format, or just leave it in the the other format in perpetuity.

Comment: @Cags Hi , i get password from customer and i want to compare this password with that password saved in maganto , how can i hash password yhat i get from customer to compare them ?